# Modifying Protostar template menu classes in Joomla 3.0

Tags: css, joomla

I'm using the Protostar template on a Joomla 3.0 site and have a question about modifying styles in its template.css file, to have the collapsible vertical menu use the same class color styles/behaviors for the text of the links as what I have for the full-width horizontal menu. I'm not familiar with all the dozens of classes (e.g., all the .nav and .navbar classes) that are specified in the default template.css file. By using customized classes in the user.css file I have the background colors figured out, and have one of the link text colors to be the same, but I'm stuck on the remaining styles I need to change.  I've been using Firebug but still haven't found a method to do this.

Here's an [album of six screenshots](http://s492.photobucket.com/user/dmack865/library/Joomla%203%20Protostar%20template%20menu%20styling?sort=9&page=1) showing three stages of both menus. Again, I need to have the vertical menu use the same text styles/behaviors as the horizontal menus.

I'd like to fix this by using the custom user.css file to modify only the required styles for the appropriate classes, as I don't want to make direct changes to the default template.css file if at all possible.

(A related question, although not as critical, is how to decrease the margins between the vertical menu items.)

So, any help will be greatly appreciated. This is the final item I need to complete for this site so I'm anxious to get this figured out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Joomla 3.0??? Why are you not upgraded to the current release?

Comment: It's Joomla 3.6.2.  Was just using 3.0 as the generic term.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla 3.x Protostar use Bootstrap 2.3.2v and have different css styles for Desktop and Tablet/Mobile view.
You need to use bootstrap media query to style it. For example:

```
@media (max-width: 979px) {
     /* menu item color */
    .nav-collapse .nav > li > a,
    .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a {
        color: #0000ff;
    }

    /* space between menu element */
    .nav-collapse .nav > li > a,
    .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a {
        padding: 3px 15px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

you can find more about bootstrap media query media query at [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#responsive)